# css margin targeting the container instead of the images

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a personal webpage using simple HTML and CSS codes. I'm currently stuck in a problem in the CSS part where I have to make 3 pictures appear in their 3 respective columns. It worked earlier before I added the div class intro. I did try removing it, undid changes, but it didn't go back to how it used to go. I'm actually self-taught and haven't been taking proper classes, so I may not understand too complicated explanation and I'm really sorry for that. Here's how my code looks.

HTML:

```
<div class="me">
        <div class="smallcontainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
            <img src ="me/me.jpg"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
            <img src ="me/me3.jpg"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
            <img src ="me/me4.jpg"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="intro">
        <h1>My name's Shinji</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.me {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 50px 50px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}
.col-3 {
    flex-basis:30%;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.smallcontainer {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.smallcontainer img{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.intro {
    color:white;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Here's an image on how it looked liked before it stopped working (without the black background)
[image: before intro]

Here's how it looked life AFTER. It seems like .smallcontainer img is targeting the img properly, but when I tell it to margin-left, it literally gives a margin only to the left-most picture, and not the other images. I've been frustrated about this for hours and I don't know what's going on.
[image: no more spaces img]

Comment: More info: I tried .col-3 img too but it didn't work... it's still the same :( If someone can help me understand what's happening, I would appreciate it!!

Comment: add `margin: 20px;` to `.col-3`, it will add a margin of 20 pixels to all sides of the div

Answer (score 2):

```
.me {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 50px 50px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}
.col-3 {
    flex-basis:30%;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 20px; /* add this line */
}
.smallcontainer {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.smallcontainer img{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.intro {
    color:white;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

try this css

Comment: Wow... that actually worked. I feel so dumb. Can you tell me why this worked in col-3 but not when I targeted the images in smallcontainer? I'd love to know so that I don't get stuck with this problem for hours. Thank you by the way!!! I'm crying

Comment: Because, the images are in the div "row" not in "small container"

Comment: You can also use `.smallcontainer .row img`